# When check out with Paypal the site still lead to sandbox.paypal.com

Tags: paypal, odoo, checkout

After I finished configuring the Paypal checkout plugin, I continue to proceed checking out, first time I can check out with my account even though the url that Odoo or Paypal lead to was sandbox.paypal.com, but with the second time I check out it don't work anymore though I can still login my account at Paypal.com, it said "Wrong username, password" times after times after I tried to login with my account at the sandbox.paypal.com url. Someone please help me, thanks in advance!

**Edit: I found this but I dont know how to get it to work with Odoo Paypal button.**

*Testing on the Live System
It is a good idea to test on the live system to make sure the switch to the live system doesn't introduce any problems. Some things to consider when testing on live:
You will need access to a Personal account with a credit card linked and a verified Business account.
Switch from the sandbox URL https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to the live site URL https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.
Pre-fund the Personal account to avoid incurring charges on the credit card.
Test transactions can be as little as $0.01 USD.
Payments may be refunded resulting in a full fee credit.
It is good practice to log all IPNs received in a log file or database.*

Comment: have you change your payment mode in odoo??

Comment: How do I do that? I start searching for it but none was found, it is still the Test environment.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect URL is sandbox.paypal.com, you need to login it by your sandbox account, not live account. 
Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sandbox-testing/managing-sandbox-accounts/ to create a sandbox account or modify existing sandbox account's password.

Comment: Ty, All I did to get it work is modify the module paypal.py in Paypal plugin to get it work with live version, not the test version.